# What is search engine life cycle from information retrieval perspective

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, search-engine

I am already aware of usage of information retrieval for search engine. But still trying to understand what can be possible life-cycle phases for a search engine. I mean for a search engine is it only about build a search engine, deploy and occasional maintenance? I assume so. Perhaps at best augment it with some deep learning or NLP algorithm. Is my assumption accurate or there can be more to it for the search engine life cycle, purely from information retrieval perspective?

Comment: This is kind of broad question, it depends what you put into your search engine. What do you mean by `life cycle`: the different components of a SE from an IR perspective?

Comment: I mean the probable steps can be 1)build IR enabled and deep learning aided system 2)deploy the results from step-1 in search engine 3) occasional maintenance. Or there can be more to it?